# NSTextStorage, Core Data and NSUndoManager - How to track changes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsundomanager, nstextstorage

Imagine a managed object that has got a transient attribute of type `NSTextStorage`. This gets archived into a binary `NSData` object on save. On edit I swap the `textStorage` of the `NSTextView` so all the changes go directly into the text storage. This way I can update other managed objects that are related to certain text locations without leaving the context in an inconsistent state and other UI elements using the same text storage get updated immediately.

The trouble is that the managed object context's `undoManager` doesn't know what to do with the text storage on undo/redo. I think it's because the undo actions are handled by the text view.

So I was thinking I could just serialise/archive the text storage on every change and replace the text storage contents with its unarchived contents. I've tested it even with longer text documents and it's not a real bottleneck on a Mac. But how do I get the undo manager to use it ? Or is there a totally different way to get it to work.

I've put a sample project up on http://cl.ly/3B1P0r2P1i0m